A countable tensor product: $\ldots \otimes M_{-1} \otimes M_0 \otimes M_1 \otimes \ldots$
It is well-known that if $R, S, T$ are rings, $A$ is an $(R, S)$-bimodule and $B$ is a $(S, T)$-bimodule, we can form the $(R, T)$-bimodule $A \otimes_S B$ as the quotient of $A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B$ by the relations $a r \otimes b = a \otimes r b$.
My question is about a countable version of this construction. Let $(R_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a family of rings. Let $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a family where $M_n$ is an $(R_n, R_{n + 1})$-bimodule. Then we can form the countable tensor product
$$
\ldots \otimes_{R_{-1}} M_{-1} \otimes_{R_0} M_0 \otimes_{R_1} M_1 \otimes_{R_2} \ldots
$$
as the quotient of
$$
\ldots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M_{-1} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M_0 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \ldots
$$
by the relations
$$
\vdots \\
\ldots \otimes m_{-1} r_0 \otimes m_0 \otimes m_1 \otimes \ldots = \ldots \otimes m_{-1} \otimes r_0 m_0 \otimes m_1 \otimes \ldots \\
\ldots \otimes m_{-1} \otimes m_0 r_1 \otimes m_1 \otimes \ldots = \ldots \otimes m_{-1} \otimes m_0 \otimes r_1 m_1 \otimes \ldots \\
\vdots \\
$$

Is this countable tensor product discussed anywhere?

As far as I understand, $\ldots \otimes_{R_{-1}} M_{-1} \otimes_{R_0} M_0 \otimes_{R_1} M_1 \otimes_{R_2} \ldots$ is an abelian group. Can we expect any more structure on it?



I would guess this is not a very useful notion. Tensor products are often used as a way to multiply elements of modules, so this construction would take infinite products. The bilinearity condition for tensor products can be interpreted as follows: modules M and N are only additive, but with maps from both into a ring A, their product in A factors through $M\otimes N$. Eg you can construct a graded ring from a module by taking sums of M^n, thus "giving M multiplication". As for extra structure, it usually comes from the remaining ring action on left and right, so probably not.
